# Deleting Global allocated memory in C++

Tags: c++

Today i tried to create global pointer:

```
int *map = new int[M2*N2];
```

then i tried to delete this in main() function:

```
delete[] map;
map = NULL;
```

But after executing all program it gives error:

```
free(): invalid next size (fast)
```

So, Is it possible to create such pointer and then delete it anywhere else?

**Edit**

Its Fixed.

M2 was M+1 (M was limit for array), After using M2=M+10 it worked.

**Thanks to all...**

Comment: Is it OK to assign an array to a pointer and then delete[] through the pointer? Just making sure

Comment: You should put the responsibility for allocation in the same function as the responsibility for deallocation, aka make the pointer `int * map` global but allocate and deallocate the actual memory in your main.

Comment: @Patashu, That's the normal syntax for dynamically allocating a block of memory.

Comment: You *should* just use a container and let it manage its own memory.

Comment: @Zeta, same error:
*** Error in `./hw4': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000000001633040 ***

Comment: @chris , in this project we must use only pointers, I wanted to use 2D arrays but its forbidden.

Comment: @user1906872, Make a simple wrapper then :)

Comment: You're doing something that is corrupting the heap. Check your code.

Comment: @futureelite7 code is ok, because it works when these pointers are in main() function. Problem is allocating them as global

Comment: Well something is stomping your heap... perhaps moving it there just triggered the symptoms.

Comment: @Patashu: The `new[]` operation returns a pointer to an array, not the array itself. `sizeof(new int[100]) == sizeof(int*) != sizeof(int[100])` (assuming that even compiles). The key thing to remember is that any pointer allocated with `new[]` must be released with `delete[]`. You can't use `delete` or `free` and expect it to work. (It *might* work, since a lot of C++ libraries' default `operator delete` definitions just call `free`, but you can't *expect* it.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error seems to be saying that, when it is trying to clean up your memory block, the size stored for the next heap block is invalid. This information is normally stored in small header blocks, just before the pointer you get from `new`.

```
...--+----------------+--------+----------+------------+------------+--...
     | previous block | block  | block    | next block | next block |
     | data           | header | data     | header     | data       |
...--+----------------+--------+----------+------------+------------+--...
                                ^          ^
                                |          |
new[] returns pointer here -----+          |
You probably wrote into here --------------+
meaning the OS can no longer find blocks after there.
```

I would bet that you are writing to memory outside the bounds of the array. In other words, you're accessing an index less than `0` or greater than or equal to `M2*N2`. (Since it's complaining about the next heap block header being corrupt, it's probably the latter case.)

Turn off parts of your code until `free()` stops complaining. Then turn on parts you turned off until it starts again. Narrow it down to a few, or one, lines that causes the problem, then fix it.

**EDIT:** Now that you've determined that a larger array *works around* the problem--*it does not fix it*--you should initialize the "out of bounds" parts of your array to some known constant (pick a number, preferably one unlikely to be in your data) and then at the end of your program, you can see what out-of-bounds elements were changed.

In the end, if your code does not work with `int *map = new int[M*N];`, then it is faulty code. If one of my subordinates told me `M2=M+10` was a final fix for the code, I'd fire them. That's nothing more than a latent bug waiting to come back and bite you, probably right when a deadline hits.

Comment: Array's limit is M and N: map[m][n].
In pointer i use map[i*N + j];
So, i created M2=M+1 and N2=N+1;
map[M2*N2] is higher than my block data. I thing it is not possible to allocate memory out of main() function and then delete in main(). It would be nice if this worked((

Comment: @EmiX: It's totally possible to allocate memory in any function and delete it in any other function.  The problem is that you're writing past the end of the array you allocated.  The problem has nothing to do with either `new[]` nor `delete[]`

Comment: @EmiX: Check your bounds for `i` and `j`. If you're using `map[i * N + j]`, then `i` must be between `0` and `M - 1`, and `j` mush be between `0` and `N - 1`. The `-1` parts are very important, and blowing past them is a common mistake for people porting from Matlab and other defective languages that start array indices at 1 instead of 0.